# D3 add link with delay

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, force-layout

I want to add some functionality to the D3 graph below, such that each link and its corresponding nodes are added after a delay of 1 second (i.e. one at a time). Is there any way to do that?

The data come from an external JSON file (not shown here) that is loaded once. Here, we assume that the JSON file will not change over time, so it's just enough if we parse the JSON file once at the beginning.

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <style>

            .link {
              stroke: #ccc;
            }

            .node text {
              pointer-events: none;
              font: 10px sans-serif;
            }

            </style>
            <body>

            <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
            <script>

            //Constants for the SVG
            var width = 2480,
                height = 2880;

            //Set up the colour scale
            var color = d3.scale.category10();

            //Set up the force layout


            var force = d3.layout.force()
                .charge(-100)
                .linkDistance(300)
                .size([width, height]);

            //Append a SVG to the body of the html page. Assign this SVG as an object to svg
            var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height);

            //Read the data from the mis element 
            d3.json("data.json", function(error, graph) {
              force
                  .nodes(graph.nodes)
                  .links(graph.links)
                  .start();



            //Create all the line svgs but without locations yet
            var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
                .data(graph.links)
                .enter().append("line")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .style("stroke-width", function (d) {
                return Math.sqrt(d.value);
            });

            //Do the same with the circles for the nodes - no 
            //Changed
            var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                .data(graph.nodes)
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .call(force.drag);

            node.append("circle")
                .attr("r", 8)
                .style("fill", function (d) {
                return color(d.group);
            })

            node.append("text")
                  .attr("dx", 10)
                  .attr("dy", ".35em")
                  .text(function(d) { return d.name });
            //End changed


            //Now we are giving the SVGs co-ordinates - the force layout is generating the co-ordinates which this code is using to update the attributes of the SVG elements
            force.on("tick", function () {
                link.attr("x1", function (d) {
                    return d.source.x;
                })
                    .attr("y1", function (d) {
                    return d.source.y;
                })
                    .attr("x2", function (d) {
                    return d.target.x;
                })
                    .attr("y2", function (d) {
                    return d.target.y;
                });

                //Changed

                d3.selectAll("circle").attr("cx", function (d) {
                    return d.x;
                })
                    .attr("cy", function (d) {
                    return d.y;
                });

                d3.selectAll("text").attr("x", function (d) {
                    return d.x;
                })
                    .attr("y", function (d) {
                    return d.y;
                });

                //End Changed

            });

            });

            </script>
```

Comment: Is there any chance for occurrence of any nodes without connections in your data? If yes, do you want them to get added first or at last?

Comment: No. All the nodes are connected. However, I need to have the nodes show up with their links (i.e. not all the nodes at once and then the links gradually).

Comment: Updated the answer and fiddle. Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Is my answer helpful?

Comment: Thanks for the response, very helpful. However, it seems your dynamic graph in JSFiddle stops before it's actually done. Can you please take a look?

Comment: I think the tick stops being called after a while. By adding a force.resume(); in the setTimeOut the problem seems to be solved. Is there any better way to solve the issue?

Comment: Yes. you are right. The layout can be reheated using resume or by restarting. You can find the reason for why resume or restart is required from [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#start)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `setTimeOut` method.

```
graph.links.forEach(function(d, i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var nodes = graph.nodes.filter(function(n,i){
            return d.source.index==i || d.target.index==i
        });
        nodes.forEach(function(node){
            var nodeG = container.append("g")
                .datum(node)
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("cx", function(d) {
                    return d.x;
                })
                .attr("cy", function(d) {
                    return d.y;
                })
                .call(drag);
            nodeG.append("circle")
                .attr("r", function(d) {
                    return d.weight * 2 + 12;
                })
                .style("fill", function(d) {
                    return color(1 / d.rating);
                });
        });
        container.append("line")
            .datum(d)
            .attr("class", "link")
            .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
                return Math.sqrt(d.value);
            });   
       force.resume();  //Restarts the force simulation.  
    }, 1000 * i);
});
```

Also don't forget to update the tick function as shown below.

```
force.on("tick", function() {
     container.selectAll(".link")
              .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
              .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
              .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
              .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

     container.selectAll(".node")
              .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
});
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aVhd8/200/)